# Filter an array by some properties in another array

Tags: javascript, timeout, wait

I need to wait for a specific result consulting over and over again the same endpoint until the result of the endpoint return an specific value. I'm going for the good way or there is something different that I can do? The idea is that the user wait with a busy loader meanwhile the process finish. Thanks

```
that.genereateJournalEntrieReport = function genereateJournalEntrieReport() {
 that.generateAndGetOMSID()
 .then(Report.reportJournalEntries.bind(that.year, that.month)) // ==> call 
  compilance with the oms operationId
 .then(Report.getOMSStatus) // get OMS status for operationId
 .then(that.evaluateOMSStatus) // evaluate OMS status and start to iterate until the job succeed
 .then(that.exportDataDownloadedToExcel)
 .catch(that.onError);

that.evaluateOMSStatus = function evaluateOMSStatus(response) {
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 switch (response.status) {
  case 'resolve': {
   deferred.resolve(response);
  }
  case 'error' || 'timeout' || 'failed': {
   deferred.reject(response);
  }
  default: {
   return Report.getOMSStatus(response.operationId)
      .then(that.evaluateOMSStatus);
  }
 }
 return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: `case 'error' || 'timeout' || 'failed': {` does not work, because it take the first truthy value for a strict comparing.

Comment: You're right! thanks, I just wrote an idea, may be code has errors. The point of the question is how can I do to manage the situation.